# Is it possible to inherit iterations from a team's parent team?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a number of sub-teams defined within my department. Each team shares the same iteration cycle. Is there a way to inherit the parent team's iterations on the sub-teams or do I have to configure their sprints individually?

My department teams are structured into nested areas such as:

```
|IT Dept
|----Development
|----Operations
```

My sprints are defined similar to:

```
|2019
|----Q1
|--------Sprint 1
|--------Sprint 2
|--------Sprint ...
```

I'd like to define the iterations at the level of the parent team and have the same applied to the child teams.

Thanks!